# Find intersections of Ways without Nodes

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, intersection, overpass-api

I'm working on a javascript project to navigate pedestrians. I use openstreetmap to give me the needed map information. I'm using ajax-requests with overpass-api to get the streets and footways (separately).

What I want to find are intersections of streets and footways, that aren't marked as such. They could only overlap each other.

Is there an efficent Query to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, I do second scai's anwser: it's mostly better using already existing qa tools. But if you *really* want to go fancy with overpass, you can also get something like that with this somewhat complex (and probably not so über-efficient) query:

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1mk

Comment: Do you have a solution to find the coordinates of the intersection point of these ways?

Comment: Nope, Overpass API can't return this kind of information, because there is no node on the intersection.

Comment: And what if I want to get this information without Overpass API?
I tried it with an overlap detection with geometry, but it's not working that well.

Comment: I would have a look at how keepright does it. Here is the [relevant code](http://sourceforge.net/p/keepright/code/HEAD/tree/checks/0190_intersections_without_junctions.php#l159). It's quite a procedure, though.

Answer (score 1):

Finding such errors via JavaScript would be very inefficient. What are you trying to achieve?

There are lots of [quality assurance](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Quality_Assurance) tools for OSM, some of them look for such missing intersections. One example is [Keep Right](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Keep_Right). KeepRight offers a GPX export which you could use in your JavaScript application.

Comment: What I try to achieve is warning a pedestrian, when he needs to cross a street. This would be helpful for blind or visually impaired people.

Comment: Oh, yes in that case it is important to know missing intersections. Did you already take a look at [OSM for the blind](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_for_the_blind)? There is already lots of research going on.